# Fix org-mode agenda viewing of stuck projects with UK keyboard #

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, keyboard-layout

So this is a bit specialised. I've used org-mode for a while now but never before the agenda command to list a "stuck project".  The sequence built in to do this with org-agenda is `C-c a #`.  This doesn't work out of the box for anyone with a UK keyboard because the `#` key is on `Alt-3` and `Alt` is bound to `Meta` (I can't realistically change this) in Emacs.  Actually I use Aquamacs but I don't think this is relevant.

I tried the method suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4786456/1972730 namely

```
;; Allow hash to be entered   
(global-set-key (kbd "M-3") '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "#")))
```

and that does indeed allow me to enter `#` symbols in many contexts but when I enter the `#` symbol in the org-agenda context I get the error:

```
org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command: Wrong type argument: characterp, 134217779
```

So I could always type

```
M-x org-agenda-list-stuck-projects
```

but that's way too cumbersome.  I suppose I could just find another key combination, but I want it to start with `C-c a`and I'm not so sure how to proceed with this.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `M-3` instead of `#` as part of a key definition. Use something like this in your `.emacs`:

```
;; fix agenda command with # for UK keyboard
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c a M-3") 'org-agenda-list-stuck-projects)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to change my input keyboard source to Australian as suggested by another SX user (sorry, I lost the reference).  That also helps in other ways as my keyboards at work are laid out in the same way now.